# vuejs $emit not triggering on 2nd component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this test component

```
<template>
   <button @click="activate()">Activate</button>
</template>

<script>
   export default{
      props : ['name'],
      methods : {
         activate(){
            this.$emit('myname',this.name);
         }
   }
</script>
```

then the parent using the component twice with different prop "name"

```
<template>
   <testbutton @myname="testF1()" name="Ricky" />
   <testbutton @myname="testF2()" name="Mechelle" />
</template>

<script>
   import testbutton from './components/testbutton.vue';
   export default{
      components : { testbutton },
      methods : {
         testF1(){
           alert(1);
         },
         testF2(){
           alert(2);
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

only the `testF1` function is triggering when clicking on button on first component and when clicking the 2nd component button, seems theres no emitted event from the 2nd component, any help, ideas is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a *runnable* [mcve]? What you've posted works [as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/dyL3gk9x/). If you need a multi-file online node-like environment, use codesanbox.io (or similar). Possibly related: you seem to have an error in the test component code: you're missing a closing bracket.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm facing the same problem and it's been a long battle to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works correctly. Don't know why you come to this problem.
Maybe you want to refactor some details in your code like this:

- testbutton.vue

```
<template>
  <button @click="activate()">Activate</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["name"],
  methods: {
    activate() {
      this.$emit("my-name", this.name);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

- app.vue

```
<template>
    <testbutton @my-name="testF1" name="Ricky" />
    <testbutton @my-name="testF2" name="Mechelle" />
</template>

<script>
import testbutton from "@/components/testbutton.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    testbutton
  },
  methods: {
    testF1: name => {
      alert(name);
    },
    testF2: name => {
      alert(name);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```